# Determine the times at which the warehouse reaches its lowest temperature an its highest temperature?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem states that the outside temperature varies as a sine wave with a minimum of $16^\circ C$ at $2$ a.m. and a mximum of $32^\circ C$ at $2$ p.m. . These are the steps I took for solving:

The equation for the outside temperature is:

$$M(t) = M_{0} +B  \cos \left( wt \right)$$

To get $M_{0}$:

$$M_{0}=\dfrac{32+16}{2}=24$$

To find value of $B$, we set $M(0)=16$:

$$16=24+B$$
$$B=-8$$

Therefore,

$$M(t) = 24 -8  \cos \left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)$$

Now I plug $M(t)$ into the newton's law of cooling:
$$\dfrac{d T}{dt}=K\left[M(t)-T(t) \right]$$
The problem mentioned that the time constant is $1$, therefore $K=1$,
$$\dfrac{d T}{dt}=K\left[M(t)-T(t) \right]$$
$$\dfrac{d T}{dt}=24 -8  \cos \left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)-T(t)$$
$$\dfrac{d T}{dt}+T(t)=24 -8  \cos \left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right)$$

Solving this ODE using integrating factor, we will have,

$$e^{t} T(t) = \int 24e^{t}-e^{t}\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12} \right) \; dt$$
$$e^{t} T(t)=-\dfrac{12\mathrm{e}^t\left({\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{{\pi}t}{12}\right)-2{\pi}\right)+12\cos\left(\frac{{\pi}t}{12}\right)-288\right)}{{\pi}^2+144}+C_{1}$$

We will neglect $e^{t}$ as said in the problem, we will have:

$$T(t)=24-\dfrac{12\pi}{\pi^{2}+144}\sin \dfrac{\pi t}{12} -\dfrac{144}{\pi^{2} + 144}\cos \dfrac{\pi t}{12}$$

To get lowest and highest temperature, we will find the derivative where $T'(t)=0$:

$$T'(t)=\dfrac{144}{\pi^{2} + 144} \sin \dfrac{\pi t}{12} - \dfrac{12 \pi}{\pi^{2}+144} \sin \dfrac{\pi t}{12}$$

$$\dfrac{144}{\pi^{2} + 144} \sin \dfrac{\pi t}{12}=\dfrac{12 \pi}{\pi^{2}+144} \sin \dfrac{\pi t}{12}$$

$$\tan \dfrac{\pi t}{12} = \dfrac{\pi}{12}$$

Now this is pretty much where I am stuck. I don't know how did the instructor get the maximum and minimum $t$ from this. We need the $t_{min}$ and $t_{max}$ to get the highest and lowest temperature.

Comment: Do you remember that $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, it all makes sense to me now :)

Comment: Good to know ! Never forget these properties. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood, what you want is to solve for $t$
$$\tan \left(\frac{\pi  t}{12}\right)=\frac{\pi  }{12}$$ Just use the inverse function to get $$t_1=\frac{12 }{\pi }\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)\qquad \text{and}\qquad t_2=\frac{12 }{\pi }\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)+\pi \right)$$

Now, may be, the question is to evaluate $\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)$. SInce the angle is small, you could use the Taylor expansion
$$\tan ^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Using it, you would find
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)\approx 0.256064$$ (the exact value being $0.256053$).

Compute now $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Well, I just plugged in the values and I actually did get the $t_{max}$ and $t_{min}$, but may I ask why in $t_{2}$ we added the $\pi$ to $\tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{12} \right)$?

Comment: @Dewton. What about the properties of trigonometric functions ?

Comment: Oh yes, I have forgotten about that, thank you so much that really helped! :)